# Significance of const keyword positioning in variable declarations

Tags: objective-c, constants, keyword, compiler-warnings

What is the significance of the positioning of the

```
const
```

keyword when declaring a variable in Objective-C, for example:

```
extern const NSString * MY_CONSTANT;
```

versus

```
extern NSString * const MY_CONSTANT;
```

Using the first version in assignments produces warnings about "qualifiers from pointer target type" being discarded so I'm assuming that the second version ensures that the pointer address remains the same. I would really appreciate a more definitive answer though. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the first case, you are declaring a mutable pointer to an immutable `const NSString` object, whereas in the second case, you are declaring an immutable pointer to a mutable `NSString` object.

An easy way to remember this is to look at where the `*` is situated; everything to the left of it is the "pointee" type, and everything to the right of it describes the properties of the pointer.

Comment: ezod is correct - However, I don't see the reasoning in adding the const, when an NSString is declared as a string constant. You can't release an NSString and you can't change it (its not mutable) ... so why even bother w/the const?

Comment: No-one uses `const NSString *blah` because even an immutable NSString might need to manipulate its ivars (e.g., caching), and an NSString might also be an NSMutableString. You use `NSString *const blah` so that some of your other code doesn't do `if (MY_CONST_STRING = local_string)` and a malicious plugin can't rewrite all your constants to be `@"I LIKE MONKEYS"`.

Answer (score 8):

```
extern const NSString * MY_CONSTANT;
```

- Pointer is variable , but the data pointed by pointer is constant.

```
 extern NSString * const MY_CONSTANT;
```

- Pointer constant , but the data pointed by pointer is not constant.

Answer (score 5):

In general, `const` always applies to the token just before the `const`.  In the second case, the `const` means that the pointer is a constant, not the thing pointed at.  The exception is when the `const` appears before anything that can meaningfully be constant, as in your first example.  In this case it applies to the first type, in this case `NSString`, so its equivalent to `extern NSString const * MY_CONSTANT`

Comment: I wish I could set two accepted answers, both have helped me understand this. Many thanks guys!