# How does the const keyword differ between iPhone and .NET?

Tags: .net, iphone, objective-c, coding-style

I'm a .NET developer coming to the iPhone, I'm still feeling my way around at the moment.

I've hit a point at which in .NET I'd normally use a named constant for readability.
I understand there's a const keyword in iPhone dev too but most examples I've seen use a #define in this instance.

What are the real differences between the two implementations?
Bonus question: How and when should they / shouldn't they be used?

Comment: Use const whenever you can, #define only when you have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of other question on SO that discuss how constants are declared and behave in Objective-C, you should look at the following:

[Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

[Objective-C “const” question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954022/objective-c-const-question)

[Significance of const keyword positioning in variable declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082799/significance-of-const-keyword-positioning-in-variable-declarations)

To compare and contrast against C#, I would point out that `const` in Obj-C is essentially the same as it is in the C language (Obj-C is a superset of C in fact). In Obj-C, constants are declared at the global scope and must be initialized to a value known at compile time. Objective-C does not support constants as class members. In C# constants are always members of a class (or struct) and must also be initialized using a value known at compile time. C# `#define` does not allow a value to be associated with a defined symbol, rather it is used to allow conditional compilation paths to be chosen (using `#if` and `#else`), which is quite different.

With regard to using `#define` to declare constants, I personally try to avoid this when possible. Values that are `#defined` are simply substituted into code at compile time - and could be interpreted differently in different contexts. It's also possible to introduce name collisions which could result in redefinitions of a value unexpectedly. My suggestions is to use `const` when you can and `#define` only when you must.

Answer (score 1):

`#defines` are preprocessor macros that are replaced in the final code. As such, they have a once defined value and can be accessed at no cost. `const` on the other hand just statically allocates a variable that the compiler handles. As such, I would (or rather am) using `#define` rather than `const` for most tasks.
Only `#defined'd` constants can be used for switch statments, btw.